# helm upgrade with specified namespace is trying to install to the "kube-system" namespace

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to install my kubernetes deployment by helm, but after passing `helm upgrade` with specified namespace, helm is installing it to the default **kube-system** namespace.

My version of helm is:

```
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.9.1", GitCommit:"20adb27c7c5868466912eebdf6664e7390ebe710", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.9.1", GitCommit:"20adb27c7c5868466912eebdf6664e7390ebe710", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

The command:

```
helm upgrade application-catalog . -f /tmp/values-nonprod.eyaml.dec.yaml --install --set deployment.version=0.3.64 --namespace playground --wait --timeout 120 --debug
```

The error what I got:

```
Error: pods is forbidden: User "guest" cannot list pods in the namespace "kube-system"
```

Comment: Check `helm ls`

Comment: I'm getting the same error...

Comment: It's the rbac issue. The service account you are using in you deployment pod does not have authorization to list pod.

Comment: Can you provide the deployment, the roles and rolebindings yamls?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not admin of our kubernetes cluster, so I haven't that file with rolebindings and I don't thinks that problem is it with the roles, because I have access to that namespace **playground**...

Comment: When I pass the e.g. command `kubectl get pods` I see the table of pods...

Comment: It seems you have some misconceptions about the rbac authorization in K8s Cluster.

Comment: So again, I want to install my deployment to namespace **playground**, but when I run that command got that error. Why then the error log referencing to **kube-system** namespace?

Comment: From which Pod, the error log did you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, to install a chart you have to use `helm install` not `helm upgrade`.

In your case when you can't use helm do deploy app, you could use template feature of helm:

```
helm template application-catalog -f /tmp/values-nonprod.eyaml.dec.yaml --set deployment.version=0.3.64 | kubectl -n playground apply -f -
```